# Converting dd-MM-yy to date in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert a date formatted dd-MM-yyyy, ex. (08/30/2019) into a date object in Swift,

```
 let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
 dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
 dateFormater.dateStyle = .long

 let startDate = dateFormater.date(from: dateInputTextField.text!)
 print(startDate!)
```

But here, startDate found nil, the format is correct, i'm confused of the reason that the date formatter is unable to create a date object from the string

Comment: just delete `dateFormater.dateStyle = .long` you can't use dateFormat and dateStyle together.

Comment: @Leo Dabus Tried this, unfortunately i'm still encountering the nil when I try to print startDate

Comment: change month and day order `"MM-dd-yyyy"`

Comment: *"date formatted dd-MM-yyyy, ex. (08/30/2019)"* the format and actual value don't match, `08/30/2019` is not in the format of `dd-MM-yyyy`.  `30` is an invalid month to start with, but the format is using a `-` separator and the format is using `/`

Comment: @MadProgrammer the separator used in the dateFormat doesn't really matter when parsing the date string. Both separators would work in both formats

Comment: @LeoDabus When you're not get the results you're expecting, best to eliminate any possible issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see you chose the wrong format. (08/30/2019)

`let dateFormater = DateFormatter()`

`dateFormater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

`dateFormater.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"`
 `dateFormater.dateStyle = .long`

`let startDate = dateFormater.date(from: dateInputTextField.text!)`

`print(startDate!)`